# How to concatenate multiple .wav files from a list in R?

Tags: r, list, audio, data-binding, wav

I have a list of .wav files `my_list`:

```
library(seewave)
library(tuneR)
data(tico)
audio <- tico
freq <- 22050
breaks <- c(0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8)
index <- 1:(length(breaks)-1)
my_list<-lapply(index, function(i) audio[(breaks[i]*freq):(breaks[i+1]*freq)])
```

I want too combine all these files into 1 .wav file, but this doesn't work:

```
index <- 1:length(breaks) 
allf =lapply(index, function(i) bind(my_list[[i]]))
```

And this is too tedious to do since I have hundreds of multiple files to create:

```
allf =bind(my_list[[1]],my_list[[2]],my_list[[3]], my_list[[4]])
```

Comment: `do.call(bind, my_list)`

Comment: that worked, thank you!

Comment: @hrbrmstr post as answer? That "bind" command, is it base or from other audio packages?