# (How) can I merge audio files in R using the av package?

Tags: r, audio, merge, concatenation

I have a bunch of ***audio files***, which I extracted from `mp4` video files using the `av` package. Now I want to ***merge*** all the audio files into one long output `mp3`.

***My question:* Is there a way to merge audio files in R using the `av` package?**

I.e. when having a vector of file paths/names such as

```
files <- c("file1.mp3", "file2.mp3", "file3.mp3")
```

I am looking for a ***function*** or ***concise workaround*** *within R* that could handle this, maybe similar to:

```
av_function_that_should_exist_already(files, output = "big_fat_file.mp3")
```

**Note 1:** I *do **not** want to paste an ffmpeg command to the terminal*. If I wanted to use the terminal or some script, I could have done that. What I would like to do, is to solve this ***completely within R***, preferably using `av`. (I want to *avoid* implementing yet another library, and overthrowing my complete code, making it into a library mixtape, when everything else already works just fine).

**Note 2:** I have already checked this post: [How to concatenate multiple .wav files from a list in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41252351/680068), I am specifically asking about av in this question, preferably not about other packages.

So, I just want to know if this is possible or not (and if maybe I'm just not seeing it). I haven't found anything in the documentation, which is mostly about converting audio and video files, not about concatenating audio or video files such as `mp3` or `aac`.

I was thinking that this should be possible using something like:

```
av_audio_convert(files, output = "big_fat_file.mp3")
```

However, this just leads to `"file1.mp3"` being written to `"big_fat_file.mp3"` in this example, so from a vector of file names, only the first element will be processed by `av_audio_convert`.

Thanks for your help and ideas in advance,

Cat

Comment: I was just linking related posts, I said "possible duplicate", if it was 100% I would have closed it. In future, please link the related posts that you have checked, and explain why they won't work in your case. Saves everyone's time.

Comment: My initial thought would be to use `av_video_convert()` to merge the mp4 files into one file and then `av_audio_convert()` to convert the resulting mp4 file. Don't know if that would work. (Actually, my initial thought would be to just paste an ffmpeg command to the terminal since you can bypass creating intermediate files, but you explicitly say you don't want to do that....)